# USB mouse unusable in Unity

Tags: 14.04, unity, mouse

Is there something special you have to do to get a USB mouse or trackball to work in Unity? I was using a USB trackball with Gnome-Shell on a laptop and it worked perfectly. When I switch to Unity, I can move the cursor, but it's incredibly sluggish and jerky, like the trackball is covered in molasses. Oddly enough, the laptop's builtin trackpad still works fine and is very responsive. I tried opening "Mouse and Trackpad" dialog and setting the pointer speed to "fast", but that has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, I found plugging the trackball into a different USB port fixed the problem.